# How to occur click function not div but button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: pic1]

If I press the boom button, I want only "boom!" to occur.
But when I click `boom` first the alert `boom` pops up, after clicking `ok` This alert closes and another alert which must pop up only when test is clicked shows up. 
If I can't move the button out of the div, how do I handle it?

```js
$('#divid1 #boom').click(function() {
    alert("boom!");
});

$('#divid1').click(function() {
    alert("no?!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divid1" style="background-color: #939651; width: 30%; height: 30%;">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p><button id="boom">boom!</button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling out to the container.

```js
$('#divid1 #boom').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("boom!");
});

$('#divid1').click(function() {
  alert("no?!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divid1" style="background-color: #939651; width: 30%; height: 30%;">
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p><button id="boom">boom!</button></p>
</div>
```